# Алгоритм деления точки эллиптической кривой на число

Tags: python, математика, криптография

Как реализовать алгоритм деления на число `Z` (скаляр) точки, лежащей на эллиптической кривой?

Кривая вида: `y^2 = x^3 + A * x + B`

`A`, `B` и число `Z` известны.

Точка произвольная, лежащая на кривой. Операции выполняются в кольце вычетов.

Для справки: [Эллиптическая кривая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Comment: @Denis а вы можете перевести ответ Sergey? Я вот не могу, потому что в предметной области не разбираюсь.

Comment: @insolor, В очередной раз убеждаюсь, что высокий рейтинг -- чаще плохой показатель (это не про вас).

Comment: @0andriy, скажем так, невозможно знать все) Перенес ссылку на википедию в вопрос.

Comment: @insolor лучше сразу в ответ ;)

Comment: @Denis, если я слышал об этом понятии, это еще не значит, что я знаю ответ на вопрос) В моем случае рейтинг тоже не показатель)

Comment: @insolor прости, если в чём-то обидел) мир

Comment: @Denis, ничем не обидел, все норм)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Более детально**:

В случае рассмотрения `ЭК` над конечном полем, алгоритм деления точки на `2` можно реализовать следующим образом:

`ЭК` – y^2=x^3+ax+b над полем `GF(P)`,

`n` – количество точек (включая точку на бесконечности),

`P` и `n` – простые числа,

`Q` – точка на эллиптической кривой, которую необходимо поделить на `2`,

`W` – точка на эллиптической кривой, которую получится в результате,
деления `Q` на `2`.

**Алгоритм**:

`Q/2 = W` --> `W ≡ Q * (2^(-1))(mod n)` то есть надо умножать `Q` на мультипликативно обратное число (inverse) по модулю.

Для `2` inverse `(2^(-1)) (mod n)` – это тоже самое, что `((n-1)/2)+1`.

`W ≡ Q * (((n-1)/2)+1)(mod n)`

**Для любого другого числа** `r`:

`W ≡ Q * (r^(-1) mod n)`

Comment: То есть, деление точки на число есть мультипликативное умножение этой точки на обратное числу по модулю.

Comment: именно Denis!!!

Answer (score 1):

Такого алгоритма не существует.
Так как на эллиптической кривой можно только прибавлять, вычитать точки и умножать их на 2.
При удвоении точки за угловой коэффициент берётся производная (касательная) к точке. Этот угловой коэффициент нельзя вычислить из удвоенной точки, потому что у неё эта касательная уже другая, с другим угловым коэффициентом.
Если бы такой алгоритм существовал бы, то небылобы криптографии с использованием эллиптических кривых.

Answer (score 0):

Применимо только в кольце вычетов.

`Q = (Qx,Qy)` – точка на эллиптической кривой, которую необходимо поделить на `2`

`P` – модуль, простое число

`N` – максимальное количество точек

`R = ((N-1)/2) * Q` – точка, промежуточное значение (умножение точки на скаляр)

`Q/2 = (R.x,P-R.y)` – результат "деления" на 2

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ответ на русский.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно учесть что не получится рассчитать точку Q/r как умножение на r^-1 mod n, где n - порядок точки Q (наименьшее целое n такое, что nQ=O), если обратный элемент r по модулю n не существует.

Answer (score -3):

`b = a / 2`.
так смысл в чем. существует точка `b`, такая что:
`b + b = a`.
делится все там на раз. но есть нюансы, `3 / 2 = b`.
`b + b = 3`.